# Css Flex Wrap Column and justify left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

List all li in direction columns on overflow wrap and justify to left

As you can see the attached code A4(li) aligned more to right.

Columns are not justified left. I want columns to be justified left.

How to align columns justify left?

```css
body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white; /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.seating_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.seating_list li {
  width:80px;
}
.seating_list li label{
  font-weight: bold;  
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.seating_list li input {
  width:30px;
  border: 1px solid #6e6e6e;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="seating_list">
    <li><label>A1</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A2</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A3</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A4</label><input type="text">
    
    
    </ul>
```

```css
body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white; /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.seating_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.seating_list li {
  width:80px;
}
.seating_list li label{
  font-weight: bold;  
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.seating_list li input {
  width:30px;
  border: 1px solid #6e6e6e;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="seating_list">
    <li><label>A1</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A2</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A3</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A4</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A5</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A6</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A7</label><input type="text">
    
    </ul>
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Suggest you edit it to improve its clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace align-items: flex-start with align-content: flex-start will get your issue resolved.

```css
body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white; /* Change my color to yellow */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.seating_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.seating_list li {
  width:80px;
}
.seating_list li label{
  font-weight: bold;  
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.seating_list li input {
  width:30px;
  border: 1px solid #6e6e6e;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="seating_list">
    <li><label>A1</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A2</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A3</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A4</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A5</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A6</label><input type="text">
    <li><label>A7</label><input type="text">
    
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
<div>
    <label>A1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

```
.seating_list li {
width: 80px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the width style prop from `.seating_list`, otherwise you cannot do much about it, that's how css works, in case you want to keep the wrap property children will be split into 2 equal columns